# jQuery Mobile with jQuery plugins

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I just started using jQuery Mobile. Can we  use plugins developed for jQuery with jQuery Mobile?

Comment: -1 Why not? which plugin? did you try something?

Answer (score 7):

Yes you can, but only some limited plugins

like you can use :

1. [DOM implementation plugins](http://plugins.jquery.com/projects/plugins/dom)
2. [Input Validations plugins](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation)
3. [Ajax plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/projects/plugins/ajax)
4. [Animation Plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/projects/plugins/animation-and-effects)

Because Jquery mobile is developed specially for the small screen device and with limited features.so can not use some jquery plugins.

Answer (score 1):

It is built on jQuery core, so you should be able to use jQuery core plugins with jQuery mobile. You could lose some of the advantages, because jQuery mobile is specifically designed to work with different mobile phones and jQuery core plugins could be incompatible or less functional with some mobile devices.

In other words: your mileage may vary, just try it!

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in this: http://www.jqmgallery.com/jquery-mobile-plugins/. You will also find many site templates, books, tutorials and other resources about jQuery mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Most plug-ins should work without issues,I've tried many jquery plug-ins with jquery mobile and so far I've never faced any issues at all,but you have to test any plug-in you want to use on mobile and see how things are working/rendering on mobile (specially if the plugin use css and images)